# Injecting parametrized dependency and manual bootstrap in Angular

Tags: angular

Before bootstraping my angular app I need to perform an async operation which returns some context for the application. Before starting, I need to init some 3rd party repository with these returned data, and then I'd like to inject this repository into on of my app's services. I'm looking for a proper, clean way of doing it, because the one that I currently have looks a bit hacky for me.

`app.module.ts` content:

```
let repo; //this is what i'd like to avoid

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
    ],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: SomeService, useFactory: () => new SomeService(repo)
        }
    ],
    entryComponents: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule implements DoBootstrap {
    ngDoBootstrap(app: ApplicationRef) {

        //some async operation which returns context data
        setTimeout((data) => {
            repo = Some3rdPartyDatabaseSDK.init(data.token, data.repoConfig)
            app.bootstrap(AppComponent);
        }, 3000);
    }
}
```

Can it be done better?

Comment: You're looking for `APP_INITIALIZER`

Comment: is it required while development or required in production (after build) also?

Comment: @Plochie in prod. Angular app will be run in iframe, and parent frame will deliver some auth data by posMessage

Comment: @akn you will need `APP_INITIALIZER` then as suggested by @yurzui.

Comment: @Plochie, nope. I have to learn about it first. Answer with example is still welcomed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this scenarios you should use, APP_INITIALIZER, This function is called when angular app is initialized.

Angular will execute provided function when the app is initialized. Angular will wait for 
the initialization if the function returns a promise until the promise resolved.

1. Create `AppLoadService` in your project
2. Create initialization method in service. (this method should return promise)
3. Create function which will refer init method in module.
4. setup `APP_INITIALIZER` in `providers`.

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6gwvrd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts) (Application will initialize after 5s)

**app-load.service.ts**

```js
@Injectable()
export class AppLoadService {

  repo: any;

  init(): Promise<any> {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      console.log('App is yet to initialize');

      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('App initialized');
        this.repo = 'some value';
        resolve();
      }, 5000);
    });
  }

}
```

**app.module.ts**

```js
import { NgModule, APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';

function init_app(appLoadService: AppLoadService) {
    return () => appLoadService.init();
}

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    AppLoadService,
    { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: init_app, deps: [AppLoadService], multi: true }
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```